# Simple .htaccess rewrite for _get variable

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on a site that uses pages with _get variables for example you can get to www.thewebsite.com/users.php?uservar=username by just using www.thewebsite.com/users/username.

The issue I run into is when I also try to add in url rewrites that also cut off file extenuation so aboutus.php becomes about us.

Can I have these two functions in one .htaccess file?

I tried this but it did not seem to work well

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /user.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have both at the same time, but you need the routing rule (the one that targets user.php) to be *below* the rule that tries to re-attach the extension. So something like this:

```
# whatever rule you have to re-attach the extension:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

# now your user routing rule, make sure you add the condition:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /user.php?page=$1 [L]
```